# Erro com o alinhamento de text Html/Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou com um problema num website que não consigo resolver.
Estou a tentar fazer um cartão de informação sem usar card do Bootstrap pois quero que a imagem fique do lado esquerdo então resolvi fazer uma coisa parecida mas só com rows e colunas e ficou assim: [image: Exemplo do cartão de informação]

No entanto não estou a conseguir com que o Nome exemplo fique por baixo do Heading Nome.

```html
 <div class="row padInternalRow">
           <div class="col-5 border">
              <img class="img-fluid float-left" src="imagens\user.png" height="175" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
           <div class="col-7 w-50">
              <div class="row border h-50">
                   <h5 class="text-left">Nome</h5>
                   <p class="text-left"><br />Nome exemplo</p>
              </div>
              <div class="row border h-50">
                   <p class="text-center">Funcao</p>
                   <p class="text-center"><br />Funcao exemplo</p>
              </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara tem uns detalhes no seu código, primeiro o `BR` dentro do `P`. Depois que vc colocou uma altura no *container*, mas não precisa como vc vai ver. Em resumo eu só removi coisas a mais que vc colocou nos elementos e inclui a classe `flex-column` na `Row` para os elementos ficarem uma abaixo do outro.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="row padInternalRow">
    <div class="col-5 border">
        <img class="img-fluid float-left" src="imagens\user.png" height="175" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="col-7 w-50">
        <div class="row border  flex-column">
            <h5 class="text-left">Nome</h5>
            <p class="text-left">Nome exemplo</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row border flex-column">
            <p class="text-left">Funcao</p>
            <p class="text-left">Funcao exemplo</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ainda estou a aprender e sou muito iniciante por isso por vezes tenho essas coisas desnecessários no código, mas obrigado.

Comment: @Afonso legal que resolveu ai, continue com os estudos :)